# Plotting a line graph with scale.quantile()

Tags: d3.js, scale, quantile

I am trying to plot a sorted array of normally distributed data so that it plots as straight line. I would like to do this using a cumulative density function, which I think is also known as a quantile function.  Unfortunately, I haven't found many examples that use the quantile scale.

Here is my attempt to use the quantile scale: http://jsfiddle.net/tbcholla/hmFqJ/3/. I set up my x scale this way:

```
var x = d3.scale
    .quantile()
    .range(d3.range(0,width,1))//this will create an array from 0 to the width, counting by 1's.
    .domain([0,simple.length]);
```

and drew my line this way:

```
var rank = 0;
var myLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate("step-before")
    .x(function(d) {
        rank = rank +1;
        return x(rank);})
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d);
});
```

Can anyone help explain where I am going wrong plotting the quantile scale? 
Can the quantile scale be used as a cumulative density function?
Are there any examples of this scale in use that you could point me towards?

Comment: Why did you feel the need to make another thread asking the same thing?  These details could have been edited into your old thread.  Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757098/how-do-i-create-a-new-scale-function-in-d3-js-i-would-like-to-create-a-cumula

Comment: Should I combine the questions? In this question I am trying to plot using the quantile scale. In my other question, I am trying to figure out how to replace one scale function with another that I am creating.